# Word for one nation taking the culture of another

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word or terminology for when one nation takes the culture of another as its own, similar to the word "plagiarised" for when one takes the writings of another?

Comment: Of course, it's not unusual for the term to be derived from the name of the "donor" country, such as "Americanization" or "Frenchification".

Answer (score 6):

The taking of the cultural aspects of one society by a stronger society is called "cultural theft" or

> [cultural appropriation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_appropriation)

There are many examples: such as [Chief Illiniwek at UIUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Illiniwek), the [incorporation of blues in the origin rock and roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_rock_and_roll), or [adoption of Buddhism in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Buddhism). This is somewhat different from assimilation, which is a giving up of one's culture for another.

The reverse of cultural theft is ["cultural imperialism,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_imperialism) in which the stronger society imposes it own culture on the weaker society.

Answer (score 3):

***[Acculturation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acculturation)*** is a term that conveys the concept of adopting a culture different from the original one:

> - the process of adopting the cultural traits or social patterns of another group, esp. a dominant one.

The Free Dictionary

One example is: 
[Westernisation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Westernisation):

> - assimilation of Western culture; the social process of becoming familiar with or converting to the customs and practices of Western civilization

Answer (score 0):

This is called **cultural assimilation**. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cultural_assimilation), it is

> the process by which a person or a group's language and/or culture
>   come to resemble those of another group

Answer (score 0):

You could often use "borrowing" in the context of cultural propagation i.e. rock music borrows a lot from the blues.

Comment: I'd say it is not "borrowing" because the comparison with "plagiarism" implies that it is not a process to be encouraged

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza that's a good point, and I suppose the difference between _borrowing_ vs _appropriating_ elements of another culture is almost entirely a matter of whether it's seen as a good or bad thing in that context. Which one would be better depends on the situation, and on the opinion of the speaker. I'll leave the answer up though, because I think both are valuable terms for their own purposes.

Comment: with a name like Juliana Karasawa Souza my guess is that you're a Brazilian of Japanese descent (I could be wrong ofc!). But even if I'm wrong, Brazilian music is a great example of how you might use both words, even _within_ the same country. Bossa nova for example borrowed heavily from both Samba and Jazz, but I suppose you could also say that white upper middle class Brazilians "appropriated" the tradition of Samba from its roots in poorer, more afro-descended working class communities in Bahia, Rio De Janeiro etc.. Which word you choose to use depends entirely on what you're trying to say.

Comment: (and of course, the latter would be a fringe view in Brazil, it's hard to find a sambista with a beef with Tom Jobim and Joao Gilberto! The point is that they're both linguistically valid constructions, but, as you pointed out, the latter contains a lot of additional meaning just by using the term "appropriation".)

Comment: You are indeed correct. The correct word to be chosen depends much on the underlying intent from the speaker, if to frame the incorporation as being a constructive process ("borrowing") vs. a predatory process ("appropriation"). Since the OP compared the process with plagiarism in creative writing (which is a big no-no), it seems that it is a process that they're frowning upon.